# Rails: Validation with lots of format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I want to validate a Nickname but I have a lot of format like this:

```
validates :nickname, presence: true, unniqueness: true, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/ }, format: {  without: /\s/ }, format: { without: /[!-\/\@\^\~\`\(\)\[\]\>\<\=]/ }

warning: key :format is duplicated and overwritten on line 38
warning: key :format is duplicated and overwritten on line 38
```

Obviously down't work in this way, how can I solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first regex covers everything:

```
format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/ }
```

but you probably want `\z` instead of `\Z` to avoid issues with trailing newlines. Anything that matches `/\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z/` won't contain any space characters so the `/\s/` test is already covered, similarly for the punctuation test.

Also, you've misspelled `uniqueness` as `unniqueness` so you'll want to fix that too.

That would leave you with just:

```
validates :nickname, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/ }
```

If you really did have multiple regexes to test then you could do it in a custom method:

```
validate :nickname_format

def nickname_format
  return if(!nickname) # The `presence: true` takes care of complaining about this.
  if(nickname ~! ...)
    errors.add(:nickname, 'blah blah')
  elsif(...)
    ...
  end
end
```

so that you could check each regex individually.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious help!